# Calculate proportions within groups in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame in R. For this experiment I was testing the survival of cells at several times with 2 treatments, and 2 replicates for each treatment. I want to calculate the percentage of cells alive at each time for each treatment/replicate.

For example, for Treat 1 Rep 1 it would be 500/500, 470/500, 100/500, 20/500, for Treat 2 Rep 1 it would be 430/430, 420/430, 300/430, 100/430

Thanks!

```
x <- data.frame("treatment"= c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                "rep"=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                "Time" = c(0, 30, 60, 180, 0, 30, 60, 180, 0, 30, 60, 180,0, 30, 60, 180 ), 
                "cells_alive" = c(500, 470, 100, 20, 476, 310, 99, 2, 430, 420, 300, 100, 489, 451, 289, 4))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group by 'treatment', 'rep', calculate the 'prop'ortion by dividing the 'cells_alive' with the value of 'cells_alive' that correspond to 'Time' as 0

```
library(dplyr)
x1 <- x %>% 
   group_by(treatment, rep) %>% 
   mutate(prop = cells_alive/cells_alive[Time == 0])
```

-output

```
x1
# A tibble: 16 x 5
# Groups:   treatment, rep [4]
#   treatment   rep  Time cells_alive    prop
#       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1         1     1     0         500 1      
# 2         1     1    30         470 0.94   
# 3         1     1    60         100 0.2    
# 4         1     1   180          20 0.04   
# 5         1     2     0         476 1      
# 6         1     2    30         310 0.651  
# 7         1     2    60          99 0.208  
# 8         1     2   180           2 0.00420
# 9         2     1     0         430 1      
#10         2     1    30         420 0.977  
#11         2     1    60         300 0.698  
#12         2     1   180         100 0.233  
#13         2     2     0         489 1      
#14         2     2    30         451 0.922  
#15         2     2    60         289 0.591  
#16         2     2   180           4 0.00818
```

Or with `match`

```
x %>%
     group_by(treatment, rep) %>%
     mutate(prop = cells_alive/cells_alive[match(0, Time)])
```

if the 'Time' is already ordered

```
x %>%
     group_by(treatment, rep) %>%
     mutate(prop = cells_alive/first(cells_alive))
```